# How to access local files in sail js

Tags: sails.js

First of all, thanks for clearing my doubt.

I want to use My .css and .js file in layout.ejs file i can do it by http://localhost:1337/js/sample.js but its difficult to load this kind of files in online server's since the port no and domain name changes. How to Use these files in layout file without going by URL method.

I tried with /js/sample.js and /**/js/sample.js Nothing is working and im frustrated.

I tried even pipeline method also

```js
var jsFilesToInject = [

  'js/dependencies/sails.io.js',

  'js/dependencies/**/*.js',

  'js/**/*.js',
  'js/**/**/*.js'
];
```

JQuery method also

```js
<script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href='+document.location.origin + '"/styles/sb-admin.css" type="text/css" />' +
          '<link rel="stylesheet" href='+ document.location.origin + '"/styles/plugins/morris.css" type="text/css" />' +
          '<link rel="stylesheet" href='+document.location.origin + '"/styles/plugins/morris.css" type="text/css" />');
        $.when(
          $.getScript(document.location.origin + "/js/plugins/morris/raphael.min.js"),
          $.getScript(document.location.origin + "/js/plugins/morris/morris.min.js"),
          $.getScript(document.location.origin + "/js/plugins/morris/morris-data.js"),
          $.Deferred(function (deferred) {
            $(deferred.resolve);
          })
        );
      });
    </script>
```

Nothing works..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer we have to add the files inside the comment of styles and scripts like

```html
<!--STYLES-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/mystyle.css" />
<!--STYLES END-->

<!--SCRIPTS-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/myscript.js"></script>
<!--SCRIPTS END-->
```

This SCRIPTS and STYLES tag will act like an linker to those External files

Answer (score 0):

If your project has the files:

- `assets/js/myscript.js`
- `assets/styles/mystyle.css`

Then the following should work in any served page (straight html resource, or anything returned from a template or view):

- `<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/myscript.js"></script>`
- `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/mystyle.css" />`

If that isn't working, some other process is causing a problem. My guess would be that you are doing `sails lift` when you are developing on localhost, but doing `sails lift --prod` in the online server.

Is that right? If so, Grunt (which comes with sails by default) may be handling some things differently between the dev and prod lifts. It may be that the files you are looking for are being concatenated and/or minified into some `production.js` file, and no longer available one by one.

If this is the case, you will have to delve into the grunt processes (related to the `pipeline.js` file, but lots of other too). You can test by doing `--prod` lifts on localhost, and if you are free to play with the online server, you can also do non-`--prod` lifts there to see if things are working in that case.